# How to read serial input from tty and write it to file in Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb

I am reading the voltage of a battery with an Arduino and am outputting over the debug output. I am feeding the debug output via USB into my PC.

Now I want to discharge the battery and read the values in a small interval. These values I want to write to a file. Like this I can build a State of Charge indicator for the battery.

I have to start small here, because I want to learn something. First I just want to see that something is arriving, so I am not as far as writing a script for actually calculating the right voltage from the bits being received. I have tried

`cat -v /dev/ttyUSB0`

to print the serial input to the console. Unfortunately nothing is arriving or well I am getting

`^@^@`

as output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you can write the reading result to the file, but you need to write a script to do that. you can use python "Pyserial" or Java JSSC, or JSerial library.

Comment: what if the user doesn't want to use python. There are several options to know the serial device output using util like `socat` or `od -x < /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: I think a python script is a good approach. I am assuming that I need to process the arriving bits and calculate the appropriate value from them line by line. Nevertheless basic functional commands in bash are also nice to know!

Comment: Python is not needed to write a reading result to a file, bash is sufficient : `cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 > logfile.txt`

Comment: If you are using any POSIX-compatible shell, you can do it with builtins only: `read -r line </dev/ttyUSB0 && printf "%s\n" "$line"` (see @danglingpointer's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use several utils like mentioned below to know the serial device output.

```
stty
socat
od
screen
```

The output what you see is the traffic information of serial device and you can hexdump to view the data or better connect the device using screen to know what information is transmitted and received.

You can just connect the device using screen, `sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0` if needed you can add baudrate at the end of screen command, this will output the serial device information.

If you just want to read the serial device input then just use something like this

```
read -N1 < /dev/ttyUSB0
printf '%#x\n' "$rtn"
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be one of the two errors, 1. The serial baudrate or other parameter error. 2. The serial input value is ^@^@, it’s ascii character,but the serial input is in unsigned bytes, cat coverte it to ascii strictly.